# Spring Kafka: NullPointerException in org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer When Updating from Java 8 To Java 11

Tags: spring-kafka

In what version(s) of Spring for Apache Kafka are you seeing this issue?

2.8.11

**Description:**

We are using spring boot 2.7.13 and java 8
We upgraded to java 11 and we started to see the following error
It happens only in prod env, in e2e it works

```
logger=listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler; Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=10, maxAttempts=9} exhausted for <our kafka topic name> org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2724) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2690) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2650) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2577) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2457) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2335) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2006) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1375) 
| at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
�[m org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2724) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2690) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2650) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2577) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2457) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2335) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2006) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1375) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(Unknown Source) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar!/:2.8.11]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

We tried to search for similar issues and investigate the source code but nothing specific was found.

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace, showing where the NPE is detected.